# Docusign API Invalid email address error with signature from document request with inPersonSigner recipient type

Tags: docusignapi

I'm currently testing an API call that will ultimately allow for an agent to provide signature and another party to sign in person. In sending the call via API Explorer I continue to receive the following response:

```
{
  "errorCode": "INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS_FOR_RECIPIENT",
  "message": "The email address for one of the recipients is not valid."
}
```

I've read in the REST API guide that this needs to be enabled for my account; it may be that my demo dev account does not have this enabled. I just need to verify whether or not that I'm not omitting any essential parameters in this call. I've tried passing in my email (as the account holder) and still receive this error. Here is my request body JSON:

```
{
  "emailBlurb": "test",
  "emailSubject": "test",
  "documents": [
    {
      "name": "ChiropractorPlusApplication.pdf",
      "documentId": "1"
    }
  ],
  "recipients": {
    "inPersonSigners": [
      {
        "hostName": "Joe Host",
        "recipientId": "1",
        "name": "Name",
        "email": "host@gmail.com",
        "signerName": "Insured"
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": "sent"
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have found a bug with the REST API Explorer in that it's missing at least one field for In Person Signers.  If you look at the [REST API documentation](http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/documentation) you'll see that there's one more required parameter for In Person Signers, which is the `hostEmail`

Try adding to your JSON

```
"hostEmail" : "host's email address",
```

And I have a feeling that will do the trick.  See page 275 of REST API v2 PDF for info on In Person Signers recipient type.  It first shows a sample request with all the options then below that it lists the required fields for this recipient type:
http://www.docusign.com/sites/default/files/REST_API_Guide_v2.pdf

Comment: That was it--makes sense. I did refer to that example and made an assumption that the email field was actually for the host. That's what I get for assuming ;-) Thanks Ergin.